# Optimization of a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm using MySQL and have a table `user_data` like this:

```
user_id         int(10) unsigned
reg_date        int(10) unsigned
carrier         char(1)
```

The reg_data is the unix timestamp of the registration time (it could be any second of a day), and the carrier is the type of carriers, the possible values of which could ONLY be 'D', 'A' or 'V'.

I need to write a sql statement to select the registered user number of different carriers on each day from 2013/01/01 to 2013/01/31. So the desirable result could be:

```
2013/01/01   D   10
2013/01/01   A   31
2013/01/01   V   24
2013/01/02   D    9
2013/01/02   A   23
2013/01/02   V   14
....
2013/01/31   D   11
2013/01/31   A   34
2013/01/31   V   22
```

Can anyone help me with this question? I'm required to give the BEST answer, which means I can add index if necessary, but I need to keep the query efficient.

Currently, I created an index on (reg_date, carrier) and use the following query:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(reg_date, "%M %D %Y") as reg_day, carrier, count(carrier) as user_count
from user_data
where reg_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-01-01 00:00:00') and reg_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-02-01 00:00:00')
group by reg_day, carrier
order by reg_date;
```

Thanks!

Comment: well the query looks solid to me, only that you do floor() when you can give a dateformat to the from_unixtime() https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Comment: Is reg_date a unix timestamp for 00:00 of that day or is it really a datetime?

Comment: @vbence it is a unix timestamp. Thus having `1359644400` for '2013-02-01 00:00:00'

Comment: @Terry I mean is the data of that field unique for a day? - So no matter when the event happened during the day the timestamp stored is for 00:00:00 that day?

Comment: @vbence I guess it's the actual timestamp `time()`, not midnight timestamp. Rounding the actual timestamp to midnight in a actual data table render other reports useless. Like `What's the peak hour of registration`?

Comment: @vbence Sorry for my poor English. It is the actual time of a day, not only 00:00:00.

Comment: @SparKotॐ I don't know about other reports, it was not in the question's scope. And the field called `reg_date` - so it makes sense that the timestamp corresponds to the `current_date()` instead of `now()`

Comment: @Terry OK, please add that to the question, because the field name suggests date.

Comment: A this point adding a field for the date would be the most beneficial. It would have much more advantage than adding any indexes or SQL trickery. - If you are running multiple reports on the same dataset consider creating an other (temporary) table with a distinct date field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can not change the table (storing individual dates would help a little), only indexes, then:

Create a compound index: `carrier, reg_date`, then group `carrier, reg_date` and order by `reg_date, carrier`.

You can create an other index just for the timestamp (it may work better for the WHERE caluse, depending your number of records outside the scope).

Further more you can use completely unix timestamps, then embed this as a subquery an an outer one can covert the timestamps to human-readable dates (this way the conversion is done **after** the group, not for each individual record).

Creating indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX bytime ON user_data (reg_date);
CREATE INDEX daily_group ON user_data (carrier, reg_date);
```

Query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(reg_day, "%M %D %Y") AS reg_day
    , carrier
    , user_count
FROM (
    SELECT FLOOR(reg_date / (60 * 60 * 24)) AS reg_day
        , carrier
        , count(carrier) AS user_count
    FROM user_data
    WHERE reg_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-01-01 00:00:00')
        AND reg_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-02-01 00:00:00')
    GROUP BY carrier, reg_day
    ORDER BY reg_day, carrier
    ) AS a;
```

Comment: Can you explain why you order in reverse order of compound index, or give reference?  What I mean is, the index won't be used in this case, right?  Should you add another compound index `reg_day, carrier`?

Comment: Why do we need Indexes defined on `carrier` field?

Comment: Thanks @vbence. I need to group by `reg_day` instead of `reg_date` so I cannot extract the conversion to the outer part.

Comment: @danronmoon Please see the sample output of the question. It is ordered by day, carrier. - The heavy lifting is the group by here I createded the index to help that one. Cardinality suggests that a carrier-first index would perform better, but ofc feel free to test it the other way around.

Comment: @SparKotॐ We are grouping to carrier too, besides it has only 4 unique values so the index must have a stellar performance.

Comment: @vbence Does the index on `(carrier, reg_date)` really accelerate the query? I think we should create index on `(reg_date, carrier)` because we are using `reg_date` in the where clause. Also, does grouping by `reg_day, carrier` or by `carrier, reg_day` matter?

Comment: @Terry You're probably right. At this point an index to help the `where` might be the most beneficial. But you can freely add an other index, and check with an `EXPLAIN SELECT ... ` query which one is used.